# jQuery API calls not returning expected data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to add Covid-19 cases to my site via javascript/api but there is something wrong. Querying by country works fine, but querying for "total" returns nothing.

So I want to get in total "infected" from all over the world and in the second row from one country.

If anyone has any idea what needs to change in the code please let me know.

```js
$(document).on('change','.corona-select', function() {
  var city = $(this).val();
  if (city == 'Kosovo') {
    $('#c_confirmed').html();
    $('#c_recovered').html();
    $('#c_deaths').html();
  }
  else if(city == 'total') {
    $('#c_confirmed').html();
    $('#c_recovered').html();
    $('#c_deaths').html();
  }
  else {
    $.get( "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/" + city, function( data ) {
      $('#c_confirmed').html(data.confirmed.value);
      $('#c_recovered').html(data.recovered.value);
      $('#c_deaths').html(data.deaths.value);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="selectBox">
    <select class="form-control corona-select" name="city">
      <option value="total">Total</option>
      <option value="Kosova">Kosova</option>
      <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
      <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
      <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
      <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
      <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
      <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
      <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
      <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
      <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
      <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
      <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
      <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
      <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
      <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
      <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
      <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
      <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
      <option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>
      <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
      <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
      <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
      <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
      <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
      <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
      <option value="China">China</option>
      <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
      <option value="Congo (Kinshasa)">Congo (Kinshasa)</option>
      <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
      <option value="Cote d'Ivoire">Cote d'Ivoire</option>
      <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
      <option value="Cruise Ship">Cruise Ship</option>
      <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
      <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
      <option value="Czechia">Czechia</option>
      <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
      <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
      <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
      <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
      <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
      <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
      <option value="France">France</option>
      <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
      <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
      <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
      <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
      <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
      <option value="Holy See">Holy See</option>
      <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
      <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
      <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
      <option value="India">India</option>
      <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
      <option value="Iran">Iran</option>
      <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
      <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
      <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
      <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
      <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
      <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
      <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
      <option value="Korea, South">Korea, South</option>
      <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
      <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
      <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
      <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
      <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
      <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
      <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
      <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
      <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
      <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
      <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
      <option value="Moldova">Moldova</option>
      <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
      <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
      <option value="me">Montenegro</option>
      <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
      <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
      <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
      <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
      <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
      <option value="North Macedonia">North Macedonia</option>
      <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
      <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
      <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
      <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
      <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
      <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
      <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
      <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
      <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
      <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
      <option value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
      <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
      <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
      <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
      <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
      <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
      <option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
      <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
      <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
      <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
      <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
      <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
      <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
      <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
      <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
      <option value="Taiwan*">Taiwan*</option>
      <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
      <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
      <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
      <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
      <option value="US">US</option>
      <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
      <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
      <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
      <option value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-12">
  <div class="mapi-info">
    <p class="title-mapi">Confirmed</p>
    <span class="nr-mapi" id="c_confirmed"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="mapi red"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-12">
  <div class="mapi-info">
    <p class="title-mapi">Recovered</p>
    <span class="nr-mapi" id="c_recovered"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="mapi green"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-12">
  <div class="mapi-info">
    <p class="title-mapi">Deaths</p>
    <span class="nr-mapi" id="c_deaths"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="mapi gray"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you properly loaded the jQuery library? It's missing from your example in the question.

Comment: One issue I see right away: your javascript is checking for `Kosovo`, but your second option in the <select> element is `Kosova`.

Comment: I've added jQuery to the snippet, btw, and that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: If you correct "Kosova" to match "Kosovo" it works — I'm voting to close this question as a typo.

Comment: There's one other issue too: the `total` value won't be available from the `/countries` endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for your answers!
It will better clarify the problem.
If you test the whole code when you click "Total" it does not show any digits and Kosovo I adjusted by changing the name from "Kosovo" to Kosovo. Now the problem remains "Total" does not display anything that is by default.

Comment: the if statement is working correctly. you are not doing anything of value within the if block.... do you mean to do this  $('#c_confirmed').html(""); (set to blank) ?

Comment: There are two issues with "Total" -- as simmer said, asking for "total" from the api endpoint isn't going to work. The other is that the `select` control _starts_ with "Total" selected, so you have to pick something else and then _go back_ and pick total to get the change to fire.

Comment: I've added [an answer that solves both those issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65242292/129086)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the API, you have a typo in your `<select>` options: `Kosova` won't work, but `Kosovo` will:

- https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/Kosova
- https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/Kosovo

Secondly, you'll need to query a different endpoint to get your `total` data.

- total data: `https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/`
- country data: `https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/${country}`

Lastly, if you want to show the total values immediately without having to select a country and then select "total" again, you'll need to be able to abstract some logic out of the `.on()` handler.

### Here's a rewrite of your logic that removes some duplication, queries "total" immediately, and corrects "city" to "country".

```js
// this function doesn't need to know about the <select> element
// all it needs is a string value
function showValuesForCountry(country) {
  var endpoint = 'https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/';

  // swap in the country-specific URL if we're not trying to get total data
  if (country != 'total') {
    endpoint = `https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/${country}`;
  }

  // no need to duplicate the API call or value-setting code
  // since we're using the dynamic endpoint value determined above
  $.get(endpoint, function(data) {
    $('#c_confirmed').html(data.confirmed.value);
    $('#c_recovered').html(data.recovered.value);
    $('#c_deaths').html(data.deaths.value);
  });
}


// when the select changes, get new data
$(document).on('change','.corona-select', function() {
  // get a string value from the <select>
  var country = $(this).val();
  
  // pass that string value to our reusable function
  showValuesForCountry(country);
});

// call this function when the page loads
// since 'total' is our default value, get that data immediately
showValuesForCountry('total');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="selectBox">
    <select class="form-control corona-select" name="city">
      <option value="total">Total</option>
      <option value="Kosovo">Kosovo</option>
      <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
      <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
      <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
      <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
      <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
      <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
      <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
      <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
      <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
      <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
      <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
      <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
      <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
      <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
      <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
      <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
      <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
      <option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>
      <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
      <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
      <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
      <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
      <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
      <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
      <option value="China">China</option>
      <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
      <option value="Congo (Kinshasa)">Congo (Kinshasa)</option>
      <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
      <option value="Cote d'Ivoire">Cote d'Ivoire</option>
      <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
      <option value="Cruise Ship">Cruise Ship</option>
      <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
      <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
      <option value="Czechia">Czechia</option>
      <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
      <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
      <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
      <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
      <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
      <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
      <option value="France">France</option>
      <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
      <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
      <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
      <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
      <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
      <option value="Holy See">Holy See</option>
      <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
      <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
      <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
      <option value="India">India</option>
      <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
      <option value="Iran">Iran</option>
      <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
      <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
      <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
      <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
      <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
      <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
      <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
      <option value="Korea, South">Korea, South</option>
      <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
      <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
      <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
      <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
      <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
      <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
      <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
      <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
      <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
      <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
      <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
      <option value="Moldova">Moldova</option>
      <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
      <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
      <option value="me">Montenegro</option>
      <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
      <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
      <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
      <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
      <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
      <option value="North Macedonia">North Macedonia</option>
      <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
      <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
      <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
      <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
      <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
      <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
      <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
      <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
      <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
      <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
      <option value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
      <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
      <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
      <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
      <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
      <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
      <option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
      <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
      <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
      <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
      <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
      <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
      <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
      <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
      <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
      <option value="Taiwan*">Taiwan*</option>
      <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
      <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
      <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
      <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
      <option value="US">US</option>
      <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
      <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
      <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
      <option value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-12">
  <div class="mapi-info">
    <p class="title-mapi">Confirmed</p>
    <span class="nr-mapi" id="c_confirmed"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="mapi red"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-12">
  <div class="mapi-info">
    <p class="title-mapi">Recovered</p>
    <span class="nr-mapi" id="c_recovered"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="mapi green"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-12">
  <div class="mapi-info">
    <p class="title-mapi">Deaths</p>
    <span class="nr-mapi" id="c_deaths"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="mapi gray"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it very complete, but Pajtim would learn quicker if you pointed out what to do instead of rewriting the code to your (very good) standards.

Comment: Thank you once again! Is there a way to do the numbers with "12,123.12"

Comment: Yes! What you're looking for is [`.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Answer (score -1):

you can fix this by adding the jquery script in the head of your html file like the following example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="selectBox">
        <select class="form-control corona-select" name="city">
            <option value="total">Total</option>
            <option value="Kosova">Kosova</option>
            <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
            <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
            <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
            <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
            <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
            <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
            <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
            <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
            <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
            <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
            <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
            <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
            <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
            <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
            <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
            <option value="Brunei">Brunei</option>
            <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
            <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
            <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
            <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
            <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
            <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
            <option value="China">China</option>
            <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
            <option value="Congo (Kinshasa)">Congo (Kinshasa)</option>
            <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
            <option value="Cote d'Ivoire">Cote d'Ivoire</option>
            <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
            <option value="Cruise Ship">Cruise Ship</option>
            <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
            <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
            <option value="Czechia">Czechia</option>
            <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
            <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
            <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
            <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
            <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
            <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
            <option value="France">France</option>
            <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
            <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
            <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
            <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
            <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
            <option value="Holy See">Holy See</option>
            <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
            <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
            <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
            <option value="India">India</option>
            <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
            <option value="Iran">Iran</option>
            <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
            <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
            <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
            <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
            <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
            <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
            <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
            <option value="Korea, South">Korea, South</option>
            <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
            <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
            <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
            <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
            <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
            <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
            <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
            <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
            <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
            <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
            <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
            <option value="Moldova">Moldova</option>
            <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
            <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
            <option value="me">Montenegro</option>
            <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
            <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
            <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
            <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
            <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
            <option value="North Macedonia">North Macedonia</option>
            <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
            <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
            <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
            <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
            <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
            <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
            <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
            <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
            <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
            <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
            <option value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
            <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
            <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
            <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
            <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
            <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
            <option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
            <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
            <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
            <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
            <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
            <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
            <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
            <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
            <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
            <option value="Taiwan*">Taiwan*</option>
            <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
            <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
            <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
            <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
            <option value="US">US</option>
            <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
            <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
            <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-12">
    <div class="mapi-info">
        <p class="title-mapi">Confirmed</p>
        <span class="nr-mapi" id="c_confirmed"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="mapi red"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-12">
    <div class="mapi-info">
        <p class="title-mapi">Recovered</p>
        <span class="nr-mapi" id="c_recovered"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="mapi green"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-12">
    <div class="mapi-info">
        <p class="title-mapi">Deaths</p>
        <span class="nr-mapi" id="c_deaths"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="mapi gray"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script>

$(document).on('change','.corona-select', function(){
    var city = $(this).val();
    if(city == 'Kosovo'){
        $('#c_confirmed').html();
        $('#c_recovered').html();
        $('#c_deaths').html();
    }
    else if(city == 'total'){
        $('#c_confirmed').html();
        $('#c_recovered').html();
        $('#c_deaths').html();
    }
    else{
        $.get( "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/" + city, function( data ) {
            $('#c_confirmed').html(data.confirmed.value);
            $('#c_recovered').html(data.recovered.value);
            $('#c_deaths').html(data.deaths.value);
        });
    }
    
});</script>
```

Comment: jQuery was missing in the original snippet, but wasn't the cause of the issues with the code.

Answer (score -1):

```
  function getCityConfirmed(city){
  $.get( "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/" + city, function( data ) {
      $('#c_confirmed').html(data.confirmed.value);
  })
}
    $(document).on('change','.corona-select', function() {
  var city = $(this).val();
  console.log(city);
  if (city == 'Kosovo') {
    console.log('yes');
    $('#c_confirmed').html(getCityConfirmed("Kosovo"));
    $('#c_recovered').html();
    $('#c_deaths').html();
  }
  else if(city == 'total') {
    $('#c_confirmed').html();
    $('#c_recovered').html();
    $('#c_deaths').html();
  }
  else {
    $.get( "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries/" + city, function( data ) {
      $('#c_confirmed').html(data.confirmed.value);
      $('#c_recovered').html(data.recovered.value);
      $('#c_deaths').html(data.deaths.value);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't correct OP's issues and complicates the code.